# Angular 5 public variable becomes undefined after navigating away

Tags: angular, variables, router

In my .ts file I initialise a public variable in the ngOnInit()

```
public statistics: Statistic[];
constructor(public statisticService: StatisticService) {
}

ngOnInit() {

this.statisticService.getStatistics().subscribe(statistics => {
  this.statistics = statistics;
  console.log('ngOnInit invoked');
});
}
```

In my template I display the data. (statistics)

After navigating away to another tab the public variable becomes undefined and ngOnInit() doesn't get invoked again.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: ngOnInit gets called only when component is loaded. If the component is loaded again, then it will get called again

Comment: I made a gif of the problem to make it more clear: http://recordit.co/uFM32tRw5M

Apparently it goes deeper than I thought. I made a reload function but apparently even if the data is in the local dataservice instance the local variable remains undefined. On the first load the local variable is populated with the data, after that it's voided.

Comment: this.teams is undefined because you need to put it inside the subscribe function since it is an asynchronous call. @WestMD

Comment: how exactly would you rewrite this? 
     this.teamsService.getTeams().subscribe(teams => {
            this.teams = teams;
          });

Answer (score 0):

You must load the components variable once again on the page which you are trying to navigate. and was your variable accessible to all classes(services) ?

Comment: the variable is declared public so probably yes